# Explanation for && usage when referring to google instance

Tags: vue.js, syntax, vue2-google-maps

I am using the `vue2-google-maps` module and came across the following syntax when needing to refer to the google instance from inside a component prop.

```
scaledSize: google && new google.maps.Size(50, 50)
```

It's used as such:

```
<GmapMarker
  :key="e.coordinates.lat + e.coordinates.lng"
  v-for="e in poi"
  :position="e.coordinates"
  :icon="{
    url: require(`@/assets/${e.icon}`),
    scaledSize: google && new google.maps.Size(50, 50)
  }"
/>
```

And `google` is a computed property.

```
import { gmapApi } from 'vue2-google-maps'


export default {
  computed: {
    google: gmapApi
  }
}
```

What is the meaning of `google &&`  and why is it required before `new google.maps.Size(50, 50)`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&&` is called a [logical AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) operator and in this case it is used to avoid errors. The MDN docs state that:

> If `expr1` can be converted to `true`, returns `expr2`; else, returns `expr1`.

This means that if variable `google` is not properly initialized it will return the falsy value instead of throwing an exception (e.g Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined/null).